# Android - Choose an image from gallery and then resize it to fit into ImageView

Tags: android-imageview

I'm trying to fit an image into ImageView maintaining the aspect ratio, it loads the image but I don't know how to resize it well. If the image it's too big I want to crop it and if it's small I want to fit the ImageView, my code so far it this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
        // When an Image is picked
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {
            // Get the Image from data

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            // Get the cursor
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            // Move to first row
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonFotoPerfil);
            // Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String
            imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                    .decodeFile(imgDecodableString));

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

}
```

and the XML for the imageView:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButtonFotoPerfil"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:onClick="loadImagefromGallery"
    android:src="@drawable/perfil_persona_b"
    android:background="@null"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `layout_width`, `hegiht` to `100dp`, `120dp` what size do you want or you can calculate size of image depend on size of screen.

Comment: How can I calculate the size?

Comment: Actually I just did what you said and works :D Thank you very much !